# how to access fields in has_many belongs to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

My problem is i want to show `emailids` of users who are currently members of that particular group, but i am not getting how to do that. I tried different combinations but still i am not able to do what I want...

---

I am using has_many through association in as follows:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships , :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, :foreign_key => "user_id",:dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships  
end
```

---

Inside my `group/show.html.haml`, I am running the following loop and I want to show `emailids` of members of that particular group:

```
%table
      - @group.memberships.each do |membership| 
        %tr
          %td= membership.user_id.user.emailid
          %td= membership.role
```

In the above code, `%td= membership.role` is working fine, which means I am running loop correctly. I am not able to write `%td= membership.user_id.user.emailid` code correctly. I am getting error as follows :

```
undefined method `user'**
```

How can I access `emailid` of users who are currently members of this group?

Comment: prasvin ..yeah i tried dat also but i am getting error as undefined method `emailid'

Comment: sryy my mistake...was giving wriong fieldname...its nw running fyn....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `membership.user_id` gets you the id of the user which is essentially a Fixnum. So, calling .user on Fixnum results in error.

Instead you could simply do `membership.user` which provides a user object, then call other methods on it as `membership.user.emailid`